# How can I change the default Maven logger?

Tags: maven, logging, log4j2

I'm trying to change the simple logger that Maven uses by default and change it for Log4j2.

I've tried adding the jars of the new logger to the Maven `lib` but it did not work.

Does any one know how to migrate from the simple logger to a newest version of the logger?

Comment: Checked this site: https://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven uses SLF4J API to log messages. By default, it uses `slf4j-simple` implementation. If you want to change this logging implementation, you just need to modify your Maven installation like this:

1. remove the `slf4j-simple` jar from the `lib` directory of your Maven installation (you might also want to rename it to `.old`, in case you want to roll it back in the future)
2. replace it with one of the alternative implementations ([Log4j 2 SLF4J Binding](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-slf4j-impl/index.html) in your case)

The configuration of the logger is then exactly the same as before ([documented here](https://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html#Configuring_logging)).